# How to create row subgroups by name in a dataframe with R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a big dataframe `list[378x87](S3:dataframe)`, and I want to simplify it by subsetting the rows in a way that has experimental significance.

I can do that because the 387 rows are in fact subgroups of the same geographical region, (with around 14 groups recognizable by the initial letters), which are named as follows:

```
DAW2-11 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.1 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 5.0
DAW2-12 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 3.0
DAW2-13 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.5 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 10.0
DAW2-21 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 7.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 1.0
DAW2-22 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.5 0.0 0.5 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 10.0
DAW2-23 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0    0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 2.0
.
.
.
```

The question is ¿How can I create a new dataframe subsetting by the first letters, DAW2 in this case, and for the rest of the 14 groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicating data from the OP to create two split groups, a solution in Base R is as follows:

```
textFile <- "DAW2-11 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.1 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 5.0
DAW2-12 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 3.0
DAW2-13 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.5 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 10.0
DAW2-21 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 7.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 1.0
DAW2-22 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.5 0.0 0.5 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 10.0
DAW2-23 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0    0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 2.0
DAW2-11 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.1 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 5.0
DAW3-12 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 3.0
DAW3-13 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.5 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 15.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 10.0
DAW3-21 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 7.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 1.0
DAW3-22 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.5 0.0 0.5 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 10.0
DAW3-23 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0    0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 2.0
"
data <- read.table(text = textFile,header = FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data$splitVar <- as.factor(substr(data$V1,1,4))

splitData <- split(data,data$splitVar)
splitData$DAW2[1:5]
```

At this point the object `splitData` contains two data frames, one for the rows from the original data frame where `splitVar == 'DAW2'` and another where it is equal to `DAW3`.

The `split()` function uses the value of the split variable to name each data frame in the resulting list, so subsequent R code can use the `$` form of the extract operator to access a data frame by its region code.

We'll print the first 5 columns of the first data frame in the list to illustrate that the first data frame only contains data for `DAW2`.

```
> splitData$DAW2[1:5]
       V1  V2  V3 V4 V5
1 DAW2-11 0.0 0.0  0  0
2 DAW2-12 0.1 0.0  0  0
3 DAW2-13 0.0 0.0  0  0
4 DAW2-21 0.0 0.0  0  0
5 DAW2-22 0.0 0.1  0  0
6 DAW2-23 0.0 0.0  0  5
7 DAW2-11 0.0 0.0  0  0
>
```

**Note:** Given the sample data, it appears that the region data is represented by the first three characters of the first column in the data frame. If the region information has a variable number of characters ending before the `-`, we can create the splitVar as follows.

```
data$splitVar <- as.factor(sapply(strsplit(data$V1,"-"),function(x) x[1]))
```

Now that we have a version of the code that produces correct output, we can simplify the solution as noted in Daniel's comment, which uses a regular expression with `sub()` to delete all characters in `V1` starting with `-`.

```
splitData <- split(data,sub("-.*","",data$V1))
```

...and the output from the `DAW3` data frame:

```
> splitData <- split(data,sub("-.*","",data$V1))
> splitData$DAW3[1:5]
        V1  V2  V3 V4 V5
8  DAW3-12 0.1 0.0  0  0
9  DAW3-13 0.0 0.0  0  0
10 DAW3-21 0.0 0.0  0  0
11 DAW3-22 0.0 0.1  0  0
12 DAW3-23 0.0 0.0  0  5
>
```

Comment: we can simplify this by doing a more direct `split(data,sub("-.*","",data$V1))`. The `substr` function also works, but there's no need to convert to factor

Comment: @DanielO - thanks, Daniel. There's always a better way to do things in R, which is I like the old programming aphorism [make it work, make it right, make it fast.](https://wiki.c2.com/?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast)